# Collar on a rim in a vertical frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Suppose we have such construction as shown at the picture. The vertical frame starts from rest with constant acceleration $a.$ Find final angle $\theta,$ assuming no friction. Also plot $\dot\theta$ as function of $\theta.$

From Newton second law i have that $ma_{collar} = N\sin\theta = mg\cos\theta\sin\theta = \frac{1}{2}mg\sin{2\theta}.$ From this i can find $\theta_{maximum}.$ But i still need to plot the graph, i think i need to build some differential equation for it.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need to build a full differential equation: draw the forces on the mass and the relationship will follow because it's asking for $\dot\theta(\theta)$ and not $\dot\theta(t)$. I suppose you are allowed to neglect the moment of inertia of A - although it is clearly rotating about the axis perpendicular to the page and is of finite size as drawn...

Comment: clearly the mass A would like to follow the direction of the gravitational acceleration...combining this with the equivalence principle might lead you to solve this with just some basic trig...

Comment: @Floris thank you for noticing that i need to dance around $\theta$ not $t$. If you like you can issue your comment as an answer and i will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to build a full differential equation: draw the forces on the mass and the relationship will follow because it's asking for θ˙(θ) and not θ˙(t). In fact I wonder whether you can't simply rotate the frame of reference until you have a single "acceleration vector" (the combination of $a$ and $g$) pointing straight down, at which point you would be looking at a pendulum with non-small deflection...